# Ag-grid React: How to put column labels of pivot columns in group heading column of ag-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have an ag-grid which uses two pivot columns, one aggregate column and two rowGroup columns. I want to show the labels for pivot columns in the row group heading column.

I could not find anything in the official documentation of ag-grid. I need some inputs please. Please see the below screenshot as an example and some scribble in row group heading column what I want to achieve.
[Screenshot of what to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nBju.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.